# Queue is unavailable but no exception is thrown in the processor of a Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a processor in a camel which is sending message to an endpoint in the camel (apache camel).

I have an endpoint in the camel xml file:

```
<endpoint id="sendQueue" uri="FBActiveMQ:queue:SEND_Q" />
```

I made the queue sendQueue deleted from the queuemanager (Using IBM MQ) and I tried to send a message from the processor to this queue and catch an exception and handle it in the processor itself.

The thing is, I never get an exception when the message is sent to the deleted queue.

I am aware that I can have exception handler in the camel file itself but I cannot do so because my processor is doing a transaction inside a transaction boundary and needs to rollback in case of queue failure.

Do you have any clues please?

The code which is written is like this(not the exact code) .

```
    try{
            JmsProducer jmsProducer =  new JmsProducer(endPoint);
            jmsProducer.start();
            Exchange exchange = endPoint.createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(msg);
            jmsProducer.process(exchange);
        } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Is your code working if queue is not deleted? Does the queue receive the messages properly?

Comment: @ Ankur Chrungoo . yes its working correctly if the queues are not deleted. The only problem is my code is not able to rollback a database transaction in case if its not able to send message to the queue(scenarios like queue is deleted). In expected scenario if the code is not able to send to the queue then it must rollback the transaction.

Comment: What type of exception are you catching ?

Comment: @Ankur Chrungoo I have made the catch block to expect any type of Exception class because I am not sure of the type of exception its going to throw.

Comment: Sounds about right! May be posting your code will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the exchange object after the process call in your try block to see if it's got an exception in it.

```
jmsProducer.process(exchange);
if (exchange.getException() != null) {
    exchange.getException().printStackTrace();;
}
```

I think you'll only get an exception thrown if it's something wrong with your jmsProducer (e.g. no camelContext).

... deleted bit about Exchange/Exception typo in original example ...

Comment: thanks @pcoates for pointing it out. Actually this is not the exact code I had written. Due to my companies policies I cannot write the exact code . This was a typing mistake which I made while writing the question. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Yes I found in case of two scenarios exceptions are thrown . One in the case of camel enpoint not set and we are calling the endpoint. Second in case if for some reason MQ server goes down just before sending the message to endpoint.